# Where can I find a list of all the new iOS 5 APIs?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm looking for a reference guide or list of all the new iOS 5 APIs. Apple's website isn't the most user friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

[iOS 4.3 to iOS 5.0 API Differences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS50APIDiff/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011042)

or

[What's New in iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1)

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why I couldn't find it myself.